# FileInputStream can not find file intelliJ idea

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, dbunit

I'm writing a DBUnit test. When exporting data from an xml-file, the compiler produces the following error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: ru/iteco/blockchain/rzd/cred/core/server/db/hibernate/dao/contract/contract-data.xml (No such file or directory).`

Here is the corresponding part of the code:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    beforeData = new FlatXmlDataSet(
            new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                    "ru/iteco/blockchain/rzd/cred/core/server/db/hibernate/dao/contract/contract-data.xml"),
                    "utf-8"));
    tester.setDataSet(beforeData);
    tester.onSetup();
}
```

The variable beforeData is of type IDataSet. The Java class resides in the folder named

`/src/test/java/ru/iteco/blockchain/rzd/cred/core/server/db/hibernate/dao/ContractDAOImplTest.java`

The xml-file resides in the folder named

`/src/test/resources/ru.iteco.blockchain.rzd.cred.core.server.db.hibernate.dao.contract/contract-data.xml`

I will be very grateful if anyone can explain what the cause of the error is.

Answer (score 0):

> "ru/iteco/blockchain/rzd/

This is a relative path, which means it is based on current directory.  The error means it does not exist relative to the current directory you run it from.

Best to load resource files from the classpath to eliminate the relative directory problem, e.g. `this.getClass().getResource(filename)`.

Consider using [`FlatXmlDataFileLoader.load(String filename)`](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/xref/org/dbunit/util/fileloader/FlatXmlDataFileLoader.html)
 as it does it correctly for you (that method is in its parent class).

Update:

> I did not quite understand what I should use from the proposed one.

If "ru/iteco/blockchain/rzd/cred/core/server/db/hibernate/dao/contract/contract-data.xml" is on the classpath, then

```
beforeData = new FlatXmlDataFileLoader.load("/ru/iteco/blockchain/rzd/cred/core/server/db/hibernate/dao/contract/contract-data.xml");
```

Comment: I did not quite understand what I should use from the proposed one. It is necessary to write something like `beforeData = new FlatXmlDataFileLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("contract-data.xml"))?` Or somehow differently?

Comment: That helped! Thank you!!

Comment: Great, any other follow-ups or is the question answered?